# Coin toss with JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I need help fixing my script. Basically, I want it to flip a coin and update a `<span>` with the result, i.e. if it's heads or tails. At the moment, nothing happens when I click the button.

**JavaSript:**

```
var heads = 0;
var tails = 0;
function click() {  
    x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
    if(x){
        flip("heads");
    }else{
        flip("tails");
    }
};
function flip(coin) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = coin;
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="click" type="button">CLICK ME</button>
<p>
    You got: <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's simply because you need to attach the event handler:

```js
document.getElementById('click').onclick = click;

var heads = 0;
var tails = 0;
function click() {  
    x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
    if(x){
     flip("heads");
    }else{
        flip("tails");
    }
};
function flip(coin) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = coin;
};
```

```html
<button id="click" type="button">CLICK ME</button>
<p>
    You got: <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer it worked! what does it do when i attach the event handler?

Comment: It **attaches** a handler to the event. When the button is clicked, it fires an event, but something needs to listen and react to it if you want anything to happen

Comment: @Amit you should include the explanation of event handlers in  your answer

Comment: oh yea one more thing is it good to use span? or should i use something else for the html

Comment: span is fine. There's no right and wrong here really.

Answer (score 1):

```
var prob1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) +1;

var prob2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) +1;

if( prob1 === prob2){
   document.write('You Got TAIL');
 }else{
   document.write('You Got HEAD');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('click').onclick = click;

var heads = 0;
var tails = 0;
function click() {  
    x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
    if(x){
     flip("heads");
    }else{
        flip("tails");
    }
};
function flip(coin) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = coin;
};
```

```html
<button id="click" type="button" onclick="click()">CLICK ME</button>
<p>
    You got: <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function flip(Throws) {
let coinArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Throws; i++) {
rndNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 1);
if (rndNo === 1) {
Toss = 'H';
} else {
Toss = 'T'
} // if (rnd === 1)
coinArray.push(Toss);
} 
return coinArray;
}
console.log(flip(10));

function flipHeadCoin() {
let coinArray = [];
let numHeads = 0;
do {
rndNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 1);
// ternary operators
Toss = (rndNo === 1) ? 'H' : 'T';
numHeads += (Toss === 'H') ? 1: 0;
coinArray.push(Toss);

} while (numHeads < 6);

return coinArray;
}
console.log(flipHeadCoin());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const coinFlip = num_of_coin_flips => {
  heads = 0;
  tails = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < num_of_coin_flips; i++){
   randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
   roundNum = Math.round(randomNumber* 100) / 100;
   roundNum === 0
   ? heads += 1
   : tails += 1;
  }
  return `There are ${heads} heads and ${tails} tails. That's a ${((heads / num_of_coin_flips) * 100)} % / ${((tails / num_of_coin_flips) * 100)} % split`
}

console.log(coinFlip(3))
```

Comment: Hi Jameel! Please take note of the parameters of the question being asked here. The structure you are using appears to be in a framework (which is not in the tags), and it fails to answer the question (flip one coin and update a span). Your code does appear to work, but fails to answer the question accurately; feel free to make some changes and give it another go at getting the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="Another way"></p>

<script>
var x; 

x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
if  (x==1) {
x="Blue"
} else {
x="Red"
};



document.getElementById("Another way").innerHTML =
"The color of the pill is " + x + "!.";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And ofcourse this still needs an event handler ;) it's late guys :)

Comment: This does not seem to solve the problem in the question, while also unnecessarily changing things that where correct in the original code